# Magento shipping cost equal products weight

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping, shipping-methods

I am looking for solution to create shipping method (or some of them) which will count shipping as (cart weight in lb) * const.
Have such solutions exists already, and if not, then what will the best way to developing it?
It should work on Magento 1.6-1.9

Comment: Have you already tried default table rates?

Comment: It seems for me that there are not option to set price to be equal weight, for example. If I have 56,78 lb in my cart I wish it to take $56,78 as shipping cost.
And there is only one possible method than can be setted with table rates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new shipping method, as described [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module)

And set the price equal to the package weight in the `collectRates` function:

```
$rate->setCost($request->getPackageWeight()); 
$rate->setPrice($request->getPackageWeight());
```